# Derive Susceptibility from Density Matrix of Two-Level System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, density-operator, two-level-system

I have come to this as the Time Dependent Equations for the Density Matrix for a Two Level System.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\begin{matrix}ρ_{11}&ρ_{12}\\ρ_{21}&ρ_{22} \end{matrix}\Big)=\Bigg(\begin{matrix}\frac{i}{\hbar}(V_{21}ρ_{12}-V_{12}ρ_{21})+\frac{1}{T_1}ρ_{22}&-\frac{i}{\hbar}V_{12}(ρ_{22}-ρ_{11})+(iω_{21}-\frac{1}{T_2})ρ_{12}\\\frac{i}{\hbar}V_{21}(ρ_{22}-ρ_{11})-(iω_{21}+\frac{1}{T_2})ρ_{12}&\frac{i}{\hbar}(V_{12}ρ_{21}-V_{21}ρ_{12})-\frac{1}{T_1}ρ_{22}\end{matrix}\Bigg)$$
My question is how should I continue to calculate linear and higher order susceptibility.

Comment: You have to *define* the susceptibility in terms of the density matrix - so you have to know what *susceptibility* is. Then you can solve this system of four *linear first order differential equations* using standard methods (note that only three equations are independent, due to the normalization.)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a set of linear partial differential equations with the tools of linear algebra. For instance, you can check out [this](http://%5Bhttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/solving-system-of-linear-differential-equations-by-eigenvalues%5D%5Bhere%5D) question.

We rearrange the density matrix as a vector $\pmb\rho = (\rho_{11}, \rho_{12}, \rho_{21}, \rho_{22})^T$ and write the set of differential equations as,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d\pmb \rho}{dt} = \pmb A \pmb\rho,
\end{equation}
where $\pmb A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix with entries corresponding to your original matrix, i.e. the entries you listed above $iV_{21}/\hbar$, $-iV_{12}/\hbar$, etc. By diagonalizing the matrix $\pmb A$ we can find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenvectors $\pmb v_n$. The solution to your problem is then given by,
\begin{equation}
\pmb \rho(t) = \sum_{n} c_n \pmb v_n e^{\lambda_n t},
\end{equation}
where $c_n$ are coefficients that meets the boundary conditions.

Comment: These are not *partial differential equations*, but rather a *system of ordinary differential equations* Apart from that, your prescription is correct. I suspect though that the OP's major problem is defining the susceptibility.

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate two time (or more times) correlators using a density matrix formalims you need something called a quantum regression formula (see Charmichael - Statistical methods in quantum optics 1, chapter 1.5), which essentially boils down to considering the adjoint Lindblad equation for the operators you want to calculate. For example

$$
\langle O_1(t) O_2(t+\tau)\rangle = \text{Tr}(O_2(0) e^{\mathcal L \tau} [O_2(0) \rho(t)] )
$$

where $e^{\mathcal L \tau} [O_2(0) \rho(t)] $ can be evaluated by considering the adjoint Lindblad equation where the unitary part is just the Heisenberg equation and the dissipative for an arbitrary jump operator $a$ (in your case $\sigma_+$ or $\sigma_-$) part is given by the adjoint dissipator

$$
\mathcal L[O, a] = ( 2 a O a^\dagger - a^\dagger a O - O a^\dagger a)
$$

For more than two time correlators I suggest consulting the reference.